# Align two time series where each has gaps

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time-series, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to merge two variables with different dates together using Excel. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
 Date        Y          Date    X
03.01.2005  2.56438 03.01.2005  2.154
04.01.2005  2.57    04.01.2005  2.151
05.01.2005  2.59    05.01.2005  2.151
06.01.2005  2.61    06.01.2005  2.15
07.01.2005  2.61    07.01.2005  2.146
10.01.2005  2.62    08.01.2005  2.146
11.01.2005  2.63    09.01.2005  2.146
12.01.2005  2.64    10.01.2005  2.145
13.01.2005  2.66    11.01.2005  2.144
14.01.2005  2.66    12.01.2005  2.144
17.01.2005  2.67    13.01.2005  2.143
18.01.2005  2.67    14.01.2005  2.144
19.01.2005  2.68    15.01.2005  2.143
20.01.2005  2.6925  16.01.2005  2.144
21.01.2005  2.7     17.01.2005  2.143
24.01.2005  2.7     18.01.2005  2.143
25.01.2005  2.7     19.01.2005  2.144
```

`X` has values on dates when there is no `Y` value (e.g. 08.01.2005).

Is it possible to create a new column (say col5) that only contains the date if it can be found for both variables and then add the values for Y(col6) and X(col7) behind it? (I.e. in my case the date 08.01.2005 would be skipped since it can only be found for the variable X but not for the variable Y).

At the end it should look like:

```
 Z              Y    X
03.01.2005  2.56438 2.154
04.01.2005  2.57    2.151
05.01.2005  2.59    2.151
06.01.2005  2.61    2.15
07.01.2005  2.61    2.146
10.01.2005  2.62    2.145
11.01.2005  2.63    2.144
12.01.2005  2.64    2.144
13.01.2005  2.66    2.143
14.01.2005  2.66    2.144
17.01.2005  2.67    2.143
18.01.2005  2.67    2.143
19.01.2005  2.68    2.144
```

Note that sometimes it is also the other way around, meaning there are dates with a value for `Y` but not for `X`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list of all possible dates on or between your limits, use VLOOKUP to populate an array including this list with `Y` and `X` from your source data then filter the array to delete rows that show `#N/A`.

If `Date` is in A1 and your list of dates in ColumnF starting in Row2, in G2:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,A:B,2,0)
```

in H2:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,C:D,2,0)
```

Copy both down to suit then select ColumnsF:H, Copy into a new sheet with Paste Special, Values and filter to delete rows containing `#N/A`. Copy result back if required.

Comment: Nice method that does not rely on VBA

Comment: many thanks for your reply. But it seems that I do not understand your answer. Could you please explain in a few words? I tried the function VLOOKUP several times but I often get an error message. Thanks